# How do you move pivots in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, pivot, unity-web-player

Developing unity web build and ran into a problem

Comment: provide more details about your problem.

Comment: please take a look at how to ask a good question and provide more details about your problem. You question is current unclear and difficult for answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: StackOverflow isn't what it used to be.

Answer (score 3):

Could be the same problem I had; it turned out I couldn't move the pivot because I had "Center" active instead of "Pivot" in the top bar in Unity (next to the move, rotate scale tools).

When center is active, the indicator for the pivot will instead indicate the objects center, exactly as for ordinary gameobjects.

try this link for more help:http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html

Answer (score 0):

Its a common problem you can uncheck the center u in top left

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: After 7 years you give the same answer as the only one already here.